# AttributeError: 'ir.model.access' object has no attribute 'type' al intentar leer un XML

Tags: xml, odoo

Estoy haciendo modificaciones en un módulo de odoo. Me manda un error en la secuencia que le estoy dando al menú ya que la vista va a aparecer como popup y eso lo tengo en la carpeta wizard, y en la carpeta views solo puse la vista del menú.

Adjunto código:

```
<odoo>
        <menuitem id="menu_mti_report"
                  name="Informes(Terrestrestre)"
                  parent="stock.menu_stock_root"
                  sequence="1"/>

        <menuitem id="menu_mti_report_carta_porte"
              parent="menu_mti_report"
              name="Carta Porte"
              action="mti_carta_porte"
              sequence="2"/>
    </odoo>
```

Al actualizar el módulo para ver los cambios me manda un error en la terminal que tiene que ver con la secuencia.

Adjunto imagen de la terminal:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No sé si la secuencia esté mal o qué podría hacer para corregir ese error.

Comment: Coloca en el título cuál es el error en cuestión. No todos pueden ver las imágenes.

Comment: es que ni yo se cual es el error solo se que esta marcando un error en la segunda linea

Comment: Sugerencia de título "AttributeError: 'ir.model.access' object has no attribute 'type' al intentar leer un XML". El mensaje de error está en la terminal...

Comment: vale gracias :)

Comment: Cuando dije "El mensaje de error está en la terminal" es porque _ahí se está mostrando el error_, no porque deba aparecer en el título :(

Comment: Por cierto, lee [ask].

Comment: Parece un error con el archivo de permisos.

Comment: tendria que agregarlo al xml y al csv de security? @Legna